# MYSQL PHP delete 'Couldn't execute query:'

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to delete a row from the database if it contains adbreak as a value but it just throws up an error. 
It should dip in to a database and delete the entry.
Unsure why it doesn't work

```
 php
// Checks to see if the key value is set
//if (isset($_GET['key'])) {
//    $key = $_GET['key'];
//}
// If the key value isnt set give it a value of nothing
//else
//{$key = '';}
$key='1';
// Checks to see if the key value is valid to authenticate the user
if ($key == '1'){
// If the key value is correct the user is granted access
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","admin_radio","PASSWORDHERE");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

$title='adbreak';
// Select mysql db
mysql_select_db("admin_radio", $con);
mysql_query($con, "DELETE FROM playlists WHERE song_title LIKE %adbreak%")or die ("Couldn't execute query: ".mysql_error());

echo 'Spam Purged !';
}
else {
// Denies the user access if the key value isnt correct
echo '<h1>Access Denied !</h1>';}
```

Comment: Try `LIKE '%adbreak%'` (or use proper backticks ` )

Comment: You shouldn't use the mysql extension anymore

Comment: what is the output of mysql_error? are you using innodb and have enabled foreign key constraints?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `'` around `LIKE` expression: `'%adbreak%'`.

Also few things:

- don't use `mysql_*` it's deprecated!
- don't use `LIKE` in `DELETE` queries. Rethink your design.